# BadMethodCallException Method eloquent does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Current project in LARAVEL get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException Method eloquent does not exist.
```

my routes.php:

```
Route::any('act', array('as' => 'ApiActividadesController', 'uses' => 'ApiActividadesController@get_index'));
```

my model.php (Actividades.php)

`use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;`

`class Actividades extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {`

```
use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'actividades';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

}

and my controller.php (ApiActividadesController.php)

```
class ApiActividadesController extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;

public function get_index($id = null) 
{
    if (is_null($id )) 
    {
        return Response::eloquent(Actividades::all());
    } 
    else 
    {
        $actividades = Actividades::find($id);

        if(is_null($actividades)){
            return Response::json('Actividades not found', 404);
        } else {
                return Response::eloquent($actividades);
        }
    }
}
```

The error throws in the `return Response::eloquent(Actividades::all());`

I've try to rebuild entire project, use case sensitive but method "laravel" doesn't seems to apear.

need help!

Comment: There is no such thing as `Response::eloquent()` what are you trying to do?

Comment: return all elements of table "actividades" @lukasgeiter via API

Comment: Are you looking for `Response::json(Actividades::all())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response::eloquent()` simply does not exist. That's what the error says and that's the problem here. What the OP meant (see comments) was `Response::json()` which converts the passed variable to JSON:

```
return Response::json(Actividades::all());
```

As a little bonus: It is indeed possible to have something like `Response::eloquent()`. Laravel's [Response Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#response-macros) allow you to add a custom shortcut to generate responses. This is how you register them:

```
Response::macro('eloquent', function($value)
{
    return Response::json($value);
});
```

And the usage: (exactly like you had it)

```
return Response::eloquent(Actividades::all());
```

Obviously it makes not much sense to just pass it on to `Response::json()`. Normally you would change the value or do something else entirely.